# RegEx: How can I match all numbers greater than X100.00?

Tags: regex

RegEx: How can I match all numbers greater than X100.00?

Comment: Why do you need to do this with a regex and not, say, the greater-than operator?

Comment: Because I would like to find these numbers in the text file. So I want to use notepad++ to define the RE to get it.

Comment: This is not the way to do it.  Regexes are for matching text patterns, not figuring out numeric values.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no attempt at writing code.

Answer (score 1):

To match numbers greater than 100.00 with up to two decimal places, you can use the following regex pattern:

```
(?<!\.)(?:1(?!00(?!\.?\d))|[2-9])[0-9]\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?
```

**Explanation of the regex pattern:**

```
(?<!                        # Start of negative Lookbehind.
    \.                      # Matches the character '.' literally.
)                           # End of the negative Lookbehind.
(?:                         # Start of first non-capturing group.
    1                       # Matches the character '1' literally.
    (?!                     # Start of first negative Lookahead.
        00                  # Matches the characters '00' literally.
        (?!                 # Start of second negative Lookahead.
            \.              # Matches the character '.' literally.
            ?               # Matches between zero and one times of the previous char.
            \d              # Matches any numeric character.
        )                   # End of first negative Lookahead.
    )                       # End of second negative Lookahead.
    |[2-9]                  # Or any number between 2 and 9.
)                           # End of the non-capturing group.
[0-9]                       # Matches any number between 0 and 9.
\d+                         # Matches one or more numeric characters.
(?:                         # Start of second non-capturing group.
    \.                      # Matches the character '.' literally.
    \d                      # Matches any numeric character.
    {1,2}                   # Matches between one and two times of the previous char.
)                           # End of the second non-capturing group.
?                           # Matches between zero and one times of the previous group.
```

**Which means:**

> Look for [the number 1 that is not followed by 00 *unless they're followed by more numbers*] **or** [any number between 2 and 9] **followed by** a number between 0 and 9, **then followed by** any amount of numbers including an *optional* decimal point followed by up to two decimal places. **But wait**, please make sure the whole thing is not preceded by a decimal point (i.e., dot).

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/oZIzjo/4).

Note that this will match `123.45` out of `123.4567`.

- If you want to match more than two decimal places, you can remove the `{1,2}` at the end.
- If you want to prevent matching the number if it has more than two decimal places, you can add an additional negative lookahead `(?!\d)` after the `{1,2}`.

Hope that helps.